# JavaFX cant see X and Y axis numbers

Tags: javafx, numbers, axis

So I have an app to read chars in every line of few files and I want create a chart of this. Chart looks ok but Im missing numbers on x and y axis any number.
Is it because the chart is in HBox or the button near I created?

My app and numbers missing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqdh5.png

```
package application;
```

/All imports here

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            HBox stack = new HBox();
            VBox buttons = new VBox();
            primaryStage.setTitle("Charts");

            final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
            final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
            xAxis.setLabel("Numer lini");
            yAxis.setLabel("Ilosc znakow");
            final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
            final AreaChart<Number,Number> areaChart = new AreaChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

            String f1 = "files/1.txt";
            String f2 = "files/2.txt";
            String f3 = "files/3.txt";

            XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
            XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
            XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();

            series = createChart(f1);
            series2 = createChart(f2);
            series3 = createChart(f3);

            Button b1 = new Button("B1");

            stack.getChildren().addAll(lineChart, b1);
            lineChart.getData().addAll(series, series2, series3);
            Scene scene = new Scene(stack, 800, 600);




            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static XYChart.Series createChart(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(r);
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName(fileName);

        int chars = 0;
        List<String> linie = new ArrayList<>();

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            linie.add(sc.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", ""));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < linie.size(); i++){
            chars = linie.get(i).length();
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, chars));
        }
        sc.close();

        return series;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow! after like 20 minutes of struggle, I have found the error.
It's because you're using the same xAxis and yAxis for both your LineChart and AreaChart.
Simply use another two different NumberAxis rather than xAxis and yAxis objects and your error will be gone.
Just comment the line

```
final AreaChart<Number,Number> areaChart = new AreaChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
```

and you will see!

Simply, like I said, use different NumberAxis for different Charts

Comment: Wow, I didnt expect this to cause this problem. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. Funny it took me a while to catch the error. I had a side error when loading the file